# Why does $ [D^n]$ (in the $Z_2$-cellular cohomology) generate $H^n(D^n, S^{n-1})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I feel confused about this because, I don't know what the $Z_2$-cellular cohomology of $H^n(D^n, S^{n-1})$ is.

Comment: What do you know? Are you familiar with the long exact sequence for relative (co)homology?

Comment: @arkeet I know that, but here it said the cellular relative cohomology, is there a definition?

Comment: Cellular cohomology just being cohomology derived from the cellular chain complex of a CW complex. So I guess this can be done from an explicit description of $D^n$ as a CW complex.

Comment: @arkeet cellular chain requires a CW complex of X first, here what the X is? $D^n$? But here we are not dealing with the cellular chain of $D^n$